# How to dynamically plot the trajectory of a particle from the ODE solution?

Tags: dynamic, graphics3d

This is what I've done:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]], 
                    Sin[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]],
                    -Cos[Θ[t]] - 0.3} /. sol, {t, 0, 40}, 
                   PlotStyle -> Green],
  Graphics3D[
           Sphere[{Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]], 
                   Sin[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]], 
                  -Cos[Θ[t]]} /. sol, 0.3]],
   PlotRange -> All],
 {t, 0, 10, Appearance -> {"Open", "Labelled"}}
 ]
```

When I put "t" as the other limit to the parametric plot, I get an error. Solutions?

EDIT: I can make the object follow the drawn trajectory. What I don't know how to do is how to "draw" the trajectory as the particle passes by.

EDIT 2: My bad, I'm new to this site so I'm still learning where to look for the answers. I just noticed that I needed to put the code for `sol`. Here goes the full thing:

`sol = NDSolve[{D[L, Θ'[t], t] == 
    D[L, Θ[t]],
   D[L, ϕ'[t], t] == D[L, ϕ[t]],
   D[L, Θ2'[t], t] == D[L, Θ2[t]],
   D[L, ϕ2'[t], t] == D[L, ϕ2[t]],
   {Θ[0], Θ'[0], ϕ[0], ϕ'[
      0], Θ2[0], Θ2'[0], ϕ2[
      0], ϕ2'[0]} == {Pi/6, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, -1}}, {Θ1, ϕ1, Θ2, ϕ2}, \
{t, 0, 40}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]`
`Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]], 
   Sin[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[
      t]], -Cos[Θ[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 40}, 
 PlotStyle -> Green]`

So basically I solved the Lagrange equations for a particle and I would like to hace an animation where the particle moves and as it does so it leaves the trail.

Comment: @belisarius Handled

Comment: @Sektor Thanks a lot :)

Comment: We need the code that generated `sol` to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
sol = First@ NDSolve[{Θ'[t] == 2 Θ[t] + .1, ϕ'[t] == 1, ϕ[0] ==  0, Θ[0] == .1},
                     {Θ, ϕ}, {t, 0, 1}]
f[t_] := {Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]],  Sin[ϕ[t]] Sin[Θ[t]], -Cos[Θ[t]]}

Manipulate[Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[f[t]  /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Transparent], 
  ParametricPlot3D[f[t]  /. sol, {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}], 
  Graphics3D[Sphere[f[T] /. sol, 0.03]], PlotRange -> All], {T, 0.01, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That trajectory appears to be fully plotted. I am trying to make the ball draw the line.

Comment: @GastonMaffei Don't expect "fully complaint" answers in these sites, but food for thought. Try to use the answers you get for building up your knowledge and as the basis for your own effort.

Comment: @Gaston, since you haven't supplied `sol` in your question yourself, the adaptation of belisarius's code to your specific case is entirely left up to you.